# List view throws an error before stream has finished retrieving data

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-listview

I've been learning `Flutter` and following an online tutorial regarding `Provider` package, at present I'm working with `StreamProvider`.

I have a service which connects to `Firestore` and returns all documents within a collection ('reports'), these documents are then mapped to my report object.

Service:

```
class FirestoreService {
Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
var random = Random();

Stream<List<Report>> getReports() {
return _db.collection('reports')
      .orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true)
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) => snapshot.documents
      .map((document) => Report.fromJson(document.data))
      .toList());
}
```

Report class:

```
class Report {
final int temp;
final String wax;
final String line;
final String timeStamp;

Report({this.line,this.temp,this.timeStamp,this.wax});

Report.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson)
 : temp = parsedJson['temp'],
   wax = parsedJson['wax'],
   line = parsedJson['line'],
   timeStamp = parsedJson['timeStamp'];

}
```

Within `main.dart` I have used `MultiProvider` and added my `StreamProvider`.

main.dart:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final FirestoreService _db = FirestoreService();

return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (BuildContext context) => SettingsProvider()),
    StreamProvider(create: (BuildContext context) => _db.getReports(),)
  ],
  child: MaterialApp(
    title: 'Wax App',
    theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
        accentColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent),
    home: Home(),
  ),
 );
}}
```

Now this is the issue, within `home.dart` I retrieve the report data and build a list view, however the list view is called before the `getReports` method has finished and occasionally throws an error when referencing the `var reports`

home.dart:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var reports = Provider.of<List<Report>>(context);
FirestoreService _db = FirestoreService();

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Wax App'),
    centerTitle: true,
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context)
                .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Settings()));
          })
    ],
  ),
  body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: reports.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        Report report = reports[index];
        return ListTile(
            leading: Text(report.temp.toString()),
            title: Text(report.wax),
            subtitle: Text(report.line),
            trailing: Text(formatDate(DateTime.parse(report.timeStamp), [h, ':', mm, ' ', am])));
      }
      ) ,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          _db.addReport();
        },
      ),
);
}}
```

For example one error in particular is thrown on this line:

```
itemCount: reports.length
```

reports being null at this point, so my question is how can I prevent the list view being built before the getReports methods has finished? what's the best way to handle such task?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var reports = Provider.of<List<Report>>(context);
    FirestoreService _db = FirestoreService();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Wax App'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Settings()));
              })
        ],
      ),
      body: reports!=null ? (reports.length > 0 ? ListView.builder(
          itemCount: reports.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            Report report = reports[index];
            return ListTile(
                leading: Text(report.temp.toString()),
                title: Text(report.wax),
                subtitle: Text(report.line),
                trailing: Text(formatDate(DateTime.parse(report.timeStamp), [h, ':', mm, ' ', am])));
          }
      ): Center(child: Text("We have received no data")))   : Center(child: Text("We are fetching data.Please wait...")),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          _db.addReport();
        },
      ),
    );
  }}
```

Comment: I've added that and it works thanks, just curious to find out if there was a more elegant way of informing the the user that 

1) we're fetching the data
2) we've received the data so display it or if we have no data, then display "no data found"

Comment: I've edited my answer and added one more condition.Firstly it will check if reports is null.If its null it means it's currently fetching reports so we will display message that reports are being fetched.After reports are fetched and reports is not null we will check if length of reports is greater than 0.If greater we will show reports else we will show a message that there is no data.

Comment: Will give that a try, I do get an error at the end of the code snippet you provided, think it's missing a colon not sure, still looking at it

Comment: Apologies.It was a syntax error. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome thanks for fixing.  The listivew no longer shows now.  not sure why.